# Assigning integer values on the command line terminal to be commands

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, command-line, terminal

I'm looking for a way of assigning integers to commands to be run. For example when I type '1' within the command line this launches file x. A '2' launches file y etc. Is there any way of doing this?
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 :) I'm also looking to make these assignments permament.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with `alias`. For example:

```
$ alias 1='echo hi'
1
$ 1
echo hi
```

Add a command you want to be executed after `=`. In your case it would be something like this:

```
alias 1='<PATH_TO_FILE>'
```

To make aliases *permanent* add them to your `~/.bashrc`, or even
better make your setup more modular and add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
############################################################
# alias definitions
############################################################
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

And add your alias definitions to `~/.bash_aliases`.

Comment: Hey just one quick question can you then ssh into this device and send just a '1' on the command line prompt and it will then make the remote computer open up that file? But thanks thats really useful and helpful!

Comment: It will if you have `alias` set on the remote machine.